# Linux, checking how much space is used on each partition

Tags: linux, disk-space

On Windows, the "My Computer" view shows how much disk space each partition/volume has.

How do I get this information in Linux (Linux Mint)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the bottom of every tab/window in nautilus it will display how much free space is on the drive you are currently browsing if you have no folders/files selected.

Answer (score 43):

The command-line tool to use is `df`.

In pretty form, `df -h` to get the results in human-friendly form.

Comment: I'd suggest `df -alh`.  This shows even hidden mounted file systems, but only local ones (no NFS or SMB drives).

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa. You must mean df --si.

Answer (score 6):

This is a reminder on the usage of `sort` with `df`:

```
df -alhk | sort -nk2  # list disk usage and sort by used blocks
df -alhT | sort -hk3  # show and sort by human-readable usage
df --si | sort -hk3   # (this one doesn't show the empty file systems)
df --si | sort -nk5   # sort by percentage full
```

Only file systems starting with '/dev' are disk partitions:

```
df -h | grep ^/dev
```

show partition type too, and hide some non-disk filesystems:

```
df -h -T
df -h --output=source,fstype,size,used,avail,pcent,target -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs
```

a better view:

```
pydf
```

list storage blocks:

```
lsblk
```

for block device attributes:

```
blkid
```

more time consuming but useful tools for examining disk usage:

```
du
du | xdu
ncdu
xdiskusage
```

Summarized from ["9 commands to check hard disk partitions and disk space on Linux"](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-disk-partitions/)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm remembering correctly, Mint is a slightly re-tooled version of Ubuntu. If this doesn't work, you may need to check the repos for Disk Space Analyzer.

You should be able to go to `Application > Accessories > Disk Space Analyzer`

Answer (score 3):

To see the size of and disk-space used of *partitions*...

for a pretty, graphical view you can use gparted.  If it is installed it will be under: 
*System -> Administration -> Partition Editor*

if it's not installed you can remedy that by using synaptic (I assume mint has that or a similar app since it's based on Ubuntu) or just typing the following command into a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the df command in a terminal window. I like to use the -k option to get the size in KBytes.